# Custom property that need to reflect in NIB/XIB

Tags: ios, xib

I am creating a custom class of UITableView with various property and enum such as CustomTableStyle (Table View Style property) and UITableViewGrouped1,UITableViewGroup2(both are custom style enum).

Now i want that when i assign this class in nib under (Table View Identity - Class)  then i want that the custom property must be reflected under Table View Attribute.

if it is possible then under Table View Attribute Section there will an attribute named "CustomTableStyle" and when i select it i will get option UITableViewGrouped1,UITableViewGroup2.

IS this possible?

Answer (score 0):

No, it isn't. Interface Builder has never supported IB plugins for custom classes for iOS (and now in Xcode 4, it doesn't support them for OS X, neither). You will have to set these custom properties in code.